# How to cluster multiple datetime data to discover patterns

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis, k-means, knn

I have a dataframe

```
usd_id   trade_datetime   position
  A     2019/01/01 08:01     1
  A     2019/01/01 08:03     1
  B     2019/01/01 08:03     1
  A     2019/01/01 08:03     1
  C     2019/01/01 08:10     2
  C     2019/01/01 08:10     2
  A     2019/01/01 08:20     2
```

for each user_id, n trade records can be made.
Is it possible to cluster these trading patterns to identify similar users?
if yes, how to do the data processing?

I have learned K-means and KNN before, but these algorithms are based on the assumption that all users have same dimensional data if my comprehension is right. Have googled but in vain.

In the above data, user_id A and user_id B should have nearest distance than A-C and B-C since their transaction time and position are more similar to each other.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, is position important regarding transaction time in the pattern you are trying to identify ?

Comment: Hi it is preferable to have the position column as one factor, but if it is impossible to include this factor, it can be excluded as well.

Comment: See my answer, but the shape of your data really depend on what knowledge you want to extract from your data. For similar users, formating to a 2D dataset with features by position as in my post could allow you to use classic clustering algorithm !

Answer (score 0):

The way I See it you have some options depending on your end goal.

### 1. Format to 2 dimensional:

You could, for each user, compute the difference between each following transaction times. This could give you a vector for each user on which you could compute some feature, for example mean and quartiles.

Resulting in something like with difference between transaction in seconds:

```
    User_ID    mean_diff_transaction  median_diff_transaction   ...
0      A                 60                      50
1      B                 40                      30
```

If your position feature is something describing "where" the transaction happened, you could make the difference between transaction only of the same position ([groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) is your friend here). Giving you a 2D vector for each user with time between transaction at each position. Then your features could also be computed by position :

```
    User_ID    mean_diff_transaction_pos1  median_diff_transaction_pos1   ...
0      A                   60                        50
1      B                   40                        30
```

When a user don't have any transaction in those place, set it to a default value, which will depend on the goal and algorithm you will use to reach this goal.

This representation will allow you to use the classic algorithm you already used like KNN

### 2. Keeping the "3" dimensional data (from a user vector point a view):

```
    User_ID      transaction_time       position      
0     A        2019/01/01 00:00:00          1         
1     B        2019/01/01 00:00:00          1          
2     A        2019/01/01 01:00:00          1          
3     B        2019/01/01 01:00:00          2
```

You could think about this data as a plot, where the X axis is the time (a tick every day for example), and Y axis number of transaction. Allowing you to plot curve of number of transactions per day for each position to see their "popularity" over time for example. The same approach could be applied with a User point of view instead of a position.

If you want to monitor the difference in time between transaction over time, just keep this difference as a vector, resulting in a "kind of" time series dataset.

Depending on what you are trying to analyse, time series data may allow you to use thing like seasonal decomposition (see [statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.STL.html#statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.STL) in python), and a whole ensemble of techniques linked to time series.